# Android set two list view in one activity

Tags: android, android-listview

In my project one requirement like two list view in one screen but problem is list view show horizontal.

I means two list view show horizontal view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code. XML code where you add ListViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create new linear layout**
1.Click graphical layout
2.Click go to next state //top third option
3.Click landscape

**Enter your like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

**Your result will be like this**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView)  is a sample project you can refer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your ListViews inside another `parent ListView` whose orientation in horizontal?